# Daemonset with privilged pods

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I am working on a client requirement that the worker nodes needs to have a specific time zone configured for their apps to run properly. We have tried things such as using the TZ environment and also mounting a volume on /etc/localtime that points to the right file in /usr/share/zoneinfo/*/* - these work to some extent but it seems I will need to use daemonsets to modify the node configuration for some of the apps.

The concern I have is that the specific pod that needs to make this change on the nodes will have to be run with host privileges and leaving such pods running on all pods doesn't sound good. The documentation says that the pods on daemonsets must have the restart policy of always so I can't have them exit after making the changes too.

I believe I can address this specific concern with an init container that run with host privileges, make the appropriate changes on the node and exit. The other pods in the daemonset will run after the init container is run successfully and finally, all the other pods get scheduled on the nodes. I also believe this sequence works the same way when I add another nodes to the cluster.

Does that sound about right? Are there better approaches?

Comment: would configuring the timezone in Dockerfile work for you?

Comment: The requirement is strange. Any process running on a Unix host, whether in a container or not, should not care what the server's own timezone is.

Comment: Strange as it is - we have tried all the other options and daemonsets seem to be last resort to satisfy the requirements. The nature of the application is transactional and is dependent on the time zone configuration on the nodes.

Comment: I don't think there is better approach of doing that. I assume that initContainer would work but couldn't find any specific example with that, because like Andrew mentioned, this requirement is strange. I think the only option is to actually try with initContainer or maybe just do it manually?